# Return only UNIQUE values from a COLUMN

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table that at a simple level looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|       "TheTime"       |   "Course"   |      "Horse"      |
+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
| "2019-07-26 16:10:00" | "ASCOT"      | "Anythingtoday"   |
| "2019-07-26 16:20:00" | "UTTOXETER"  | "Blazon"          |
| "2019-07-26 16:45:00" | "ASCOT"      | "Harry Hurricane" |
| "2019-07-26 18:30:00" | "YORK"       | "Qaaraat"         |
| "2019-07-26 18:30:00" | "YORK"       | "Russian Realm"   |
| "2019-07-26 18:35:00" | "DOWN ROYAL" | "Abstraction"     |
| "2019-07-26 18:50:00" | "WEXFORD"    | "Naughty Molly"   |
| "2019-07-26 19:50:00" | "WEXFORD"    | "Persian Wind"    |
| "2019-07-26 20:20:00" | "WEXFORD"    | "Whoyakodding"    |
+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to remove any rows where the "TheTime" column has no matches.

The end result would look like the following

```
+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|       "TheTime"       |   "Course"   |      "Horse"      |
+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
| "2019-07-26 16:10:00" | "ASCOT"      | "Anythingtoday"   |
| "2019-07-26 16:20:00" | "UTTOXETER"  | "Blazon"          |
| "2019-07-26 16:45:00" | "ASCOT"      | "Harry Hurricane" |
| "2019-07-26 18:35:00" | "DOWN ROYAL" | "Abstraction"     |
| "2019-07-26 18:50:00" | "WEXFORD"    | "Naughty Molly"   |
| "2019-07-26 19:50:00" | "WEXFORD"    | "Persian Wind"    |
| "2019-07-26 20:20:00" | "WEXFORD"    | "Whoyakodding"    |
+-----------------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

This is because there are 2 horses running in the 18:30 at york

```
"2019-07-26 18:30:00"   "YORK"  "Qaaraat"
"2019-07-26 18:30:00"   "YORK"  "Russian Realm"
```

I know I cannot use Group By or DISTINCT for this type of query so how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `TheTime` and then filter only those groups which have exactly 1 member:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY TheTime HAVING COUNT(Course)=1
```

Comment: This works great and very simple (I was thinking to complex)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.thetime = t.thetime and
                        t2.course = t.course and
                        t2.horse <> t.horse
                 );
```

Alternatively, you can use aggregation:

```
select thetime, course, max(horse)
from t
group by thetime, course
having count(*) = 1;
```

If there is only one row for a time/course combination, then `max(horse)` returns the name of that horse.